# How to specify location where test results are saved to?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mstest

When automating tests, I would use MSTest.exe, the command-line program. I would pass in a parameter which would specify the location where I want the test result file to save to.

My problem is that I want to be able to run tests from the Visual Studio GUI, and still be able to specify a location for the test results file.

My reason for this is that I am writing a bit of code to read the test result file (since it's in XML format) and to then email the results to a specified email address.

I want my test to get the test result file from the same location regardless of whether I run the test via MSTest.exe or via the Visual Studio GUI.

I know that I can do this in the GUI by selecting the 'Export Test Run Details' option from the 'Test Results' window. I want to know how to do this programmatically, so I can perform the action automatically once the test run has completed.

... alternatively, aren't there classes that should allow me to access the test result information programmatically? I believe there is a TestResult class that might help me, for example, although I'm not quite sure how to use this. I also noticed that the TestContext class has properties such as 'DeploymentDirectory', but they are read-only.

Also, I read elsewhere on-line that with VS2008, you can edit the .testrunconfig file to add the following line in the TestRunConfiguration element:

> '<'Deployment userDeploymentRoot="C:\TestResults" useDefaultDeploymentRoot="false" />

But the .testrunconfig file doesn't exist in my solution, and the TestRunConfiguration element doesn't appear in my .vsmdi file.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *Clean up Script* which will copy the `Test Results` files to a pre-defined directory.

Create a batch with the following code:

```
::Set the path where the result files will be copied
set TargetDirectory = "C:\..."
::copy the results file
xcopy /s /y "%TestDir%.trx" %TargetDirectory%
```

Note the `%TestDir%` variable is autamatically created by the Visual Studio to the `qtcleanup.bat` which is located to the default test results output directory for each test run.

Your batch file's content will be appended to the `qtcleanup.bat` so you can use the above variable. You can also open it to see the rest available variables.

After you created your batch file go to visual studio, open the `*.testsettings`, click on the `Setup and Cleanup Scripts` and select your .bat file.

It will run every time at the end of the test run.

Comment: ah... good shout! One thing though - the code I have for getting and reading the test results exists in an [AssemblyCleanUp] method. Which will run first, the batch script or the AssemblyCleanUp method? I may have to give this a try to see if this solves the issue.

Comment: I think the `Setup and Cleanup scripts` are running before/after the Assembly Setup and Cleanup methods.

Comment: In that case, I could perhaps create an exe to read the test results and run that as the cleanup script - and I can simply use the TestContext.TestDir property to get the location of the .trx file and pass it as an argument to the exe file. Not a perfect solution, but I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: On second thoughts... I don't think it's possible to pass in variables from the running test to the cleanup script...

Comment: Not from test, but from the clean script itself. Use the script from my answer as your cleanup script to run your `exe`from it. Add the following line: `%pathForExe%\some.exe %TestDir%`.

Comment: The problem is that I also wanted to pass in other parameters into the exe too, so instead I used Process.Start() to run the exe program as the very last step in my AssemblyCleanup method. I added a few seconds sleep in the exe, to give time for the TRX results file to be created.

Comment: Let's discuss it [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14676/discussion-between-schaliasos-and-ciarang) if you have more questions.